# Compare items inside list with names in directory python

Tags: python, mysql, list, file

I have a list which contains the rows of my MySQL table which looks like this `list1 = [a,b,c,d]`. I also have a directoy which contains more then 100 folders including a few folders with the same name inside the ones in `list1`. Now I only want to enter the folders which have the same name as the ones in my list1. How do I do that? This is my current code but it doesnt seem to work:

```
source = r'c:\data\OVER\Desktop\Source'
    
list1= [i[0] for i in cursor.fetchall()]
directory= os.listdir(source)

if rows_mysql in directory:
      os.listdir(source)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What is your error that "doesn't seem to work"?

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way to find items common to two lists is to convert them to sets and then to find the intersection of those sets:

```
s1 = set(list1)
s2 = set(directory)
matches = s1 & s2 # common to both
for match in matches:
    os.listdir(match)
```

I have no idea what your variable `rows_mysql` is. Without using sets, your code should have been:

```
for item in list1:
   if item in directory:
      os.listdir(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

@Booboo. Thank you.

Well I actually found a solution, this worked for me. Might help you to:

```
source = r'c:\data\OVER\Desktop\Source'
    
list1= [i[0] for i in cursor.fetchall()]
directory= os.listdir(source)

#print(list1)
#print(directory)

for x in list1:
    if x in directory:
        subdir_path = os.path.join(source, x)
```